# Why is windows installation media giving Boot\BCD error?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I've tried creating a windows 8 and 7 installation media from Ubuntu 16.04 using

- WoeUSB
- UNetBootIn
- GParted

In all the above cases I got the Boot\BCD error. Error code was 0xc000000e.

The BIOS supports only legacy boot, motherboard P5RD2-VM.

I've used MBR with FAT32 partition.

Not only that, I've used a windows PC to create the bootable media using PowerISO. The problem persists.

The media booted fine when tested on my friend's newer Computer. It supports UEFI.

So recently, I've used WoeUSB to flash the ISO directly into an HDD partition.
When flashing Win 8, it booted to the logo, and then some flashing hex numbers appeared and pc rebooted.

In case of Win 7, the mouse pointer appeared on a black screen and that was it.

PS: I've had no problem booting from disks for windows installation, nor USBs for linux installation. Unfortunately, the DVD reader has died.

Comment: Also asked here: https://superuser.com/questions/1642939/why-am-i-getting-boot-bcd-error-when-booting-a-windows-installation-usb

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Comment: No karel, I've tried everything but it seems my PC doesn't support booting USBs flashed with windows. Not just that, flashing the ISO into a hardisk partition doesn't work as well.